# How to develope Web modules

Tags: php, module, pear

I'm looking to buid a paid subscription service that I can send to website builders.

I want to target PHP developers using virtual servers. However I would like to compile the code into some sort of library so as not to allow the customers to view the code that I have given them.

I want to know what options I have to build these modules ? I don't think its possible to compile PHP and I was looking a PEAR ?

What would be the best choices ?

Comment: This is about as broad as asking about making websites - can you explain a little more?

Comment: Sorry if it seems vague, I'm trying not to give away my ideas. Say for instance I build a login component for a website. What I want is to distribute this login component to website builders where they could drop it onto their website and it would just work. However I don't want them to be able to view or edit the code ? Is there a way of building modules like this for websites ? I think transforming the PHP might be the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [PHP's bytecode compiler](http://php.net/bcompiler). I've been using it to deliver closed-source PHP applications to some of my clients. I don't know exactly how hard it would be to reverse it back to plain source code, but it should be relatively hard. Do note that any strings in your code are readable on the generated bytecode, so don't hold anything sensitive as a plain string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question but maybe using Ioncube (http://www.ioncube.com/) could be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your question either. But you can't compile your PHP directly. You can obfuscate it. Or you can use the HipHop compiler to compile your code to highly optimized C++ code and then it's compiled.

more information about obfuscating:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code

more information about hipHop:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_(software)